# Google promises that Fusion tables can be imported into Google Sheets but how?

Tags: google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

Google states that fusion tables could be imported into sheets and turned into maps but I cannot find any information on how to import Fusion tables nor how to turn them into maps similar as in Fusion Tables. Please help!

Googled for hours...

Answer (score 1):

One option is to [download](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2548807) the Fusion Table as CSV. Then [import](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/40608) the CSV into Google Sheets.
You can then use this [Mapping from a Google Spreadsheet](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/learn/mapping-from-a-google-spreadsheet/) tutorial to learn how to create a map from your data.

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.google.com/fusiontables/?hl=en

> Google Fusion Tables will not be available after Dec. 3, 2019. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417)

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/fusion-tables

> Warning: The Fusion Tables API that this service enabled was deprecated on December 11, 2018. You can continue to use the advanced service until December 3, 2019, when the API will be fully shutdown. See the Fusion Tables help center for more details.

Anyway, the above link include code samples. I think that this links will help you on your quest is you still are interested on using Fusion Tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Fusion Table Archive Tool and it copies your selected google fusion tables (to your google drive) into google sheets. I am doing it now. I hope it works. Make sure you download your fusion table in .csv format as a backup.

Also, if you are looking at a map in fusion tables then you can download the fusion table in KML format and then you can open these KMLs in google earth and it will also show the bubble messages that you had in google fusion table maps when you click on the points on your map.

Personally, I am planning to write some python programs to bring up my maps in the future using a library called Folium that looks like it can display maps easily. I will use python to update my data in my .csv files and add new rows (eventually I may migrate to a database of some sort like SQL, still mulling this over.)

There is an add-on for google sheets called "mapping sheets" that can build a map from your data in sheets. It might be useful.

https://fusiontables-archive.withgoogle.com/export

https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html

https://gsuite.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/mapping_sheets/736233853391?hl=en&pann=sheets_addon_widget